# How to get the String Value of Textbox

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

I try to write a program that when I add many textbox programmatically (using button) where you can click the textbox and it will Toast the String inside of it. but everytime I add a new Textbox with a String on it . when I click the former textbox it Toast the New one. I hope someone help me

```
        public void getText(){

            TableRow legRow = new TableRow(this);

            tvAddress = new TextView(this);


            tvAddress.setTextSize(13);
            tvAddress.setWidth(275);
            tvAddress.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL| Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            tvAddress.setHighlightColor(Color.parseColor("#4398ee"));
            tvAddress.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            tvAddress.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 5);
            tvAddress.setTag(addresss);

    //        tvAddress.setTag("et"+x);
            tvAddress.setHint("Address "+x);
            tvAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(PointOfInterestActivityTable.this, ""+tvAddress.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    legRow.addView(tvAddress);
    }
```

Comment: Can you declare the reference `tvAddress` inside `getText()` and check?

Comment: how im new at android studio

Comment: I mean declare `TextView tvAddress` variable inside the method instead of outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `tvAddress.setText("Hello");` above Toast method.

Then in the Toast method instead of `""+tvAddress.getTag()` try using `tvAddress.getText().toString()`